acvtool 2.3, INSTRUMENTATION_CODE=0 during "acv start <package-name>"
I need to get code coverage of an Android App using my Android App testing module. For that purpose, I tried acvtool. I've followed this tutorial.
I successfully instrumented the com.aimp.player.apk and installed it on my device.
> acv instrument <package_name>.apk
> acv install instr_<package_name>.apk # instr_<package_name>.apk is the instrumented version of the .apk 

After that, when I executed acv start com.aimp.player , I got the following error.

> acv start com.aimp.player

Press Ctrl+C to finish ...
INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=Process crashed.
INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0

OS: Ubuntu 24.04
Virtual Env Manager: Conda
Device: Samsung Galaxy A05
adb version info :
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 34.0.4-debian
Installed as /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
Running on Linux 6.8.0-45-generic (x86_64)

aapt2, apksigner, zipalign version : 35.0.0
ACVPatcher version : v1.0.3
I executed acv start com.aimp.player and expected it to run as long as the testing module interacted with the app and generate the code coverage eventually.

That tutorial is outdated already. No need for 'start' command anymore, just run the app and call the 'acv snap ' command (checkout the readme in the acvtool repository).
